# Excel VBA doesn't recognize shape selection in Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

```
Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub getshapedata()
On Error GoTo line1
Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext
Dim nextrow

shapeslide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
shapename = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
shapetext = pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text
friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")

nextrow = Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheet1.Range("a" & nextrow) = shapeslide
Sheet1.Range("b" & nextrow) = shapename
Sheet1.Range("c" & nextrow) = shapetext
Sheet1.Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname

Exit Sub



line1:
MsgBox "No item selected"

End Sub

Sub writedata()
Dim c As Object
Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("a2:a" & Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = Sheet1.Range("c" & c.Row).Text
friendlyname = Sheet1.Range("d" & c.Row)
pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext

Next c

End Sub
```

Hi all 
I am using the above code to update the data in powerpoint from Excel VBA, I am using it on office 2016 on Windows 7.

following exactly the code, when I select a shape, it recognizes the box and content, then asks me to assign a friendly name , but then jumps to the error : no item selected, the line indicated in debugging is :

```
nextrow = Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to resolve this

Comment: Comment out the error handler and see where (and what) the actual error is.

Comment: Unless I don't know what is the effective method, but I have tried it and I know which line bugs the error, but in theory it should work...

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you, I found the solution and added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and I would put it here for anyone who might use it in the future :

```
Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub getshapedata()
Dim shapeslide As Integer
Dim shapename As String
Dim shapetext As String
Dim friendlyname As String
Dim nextrow As Long

On Error GoTo line1
Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
shapeslide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
shapename = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
shapetext = pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text
friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")

With ActiveSheet
    nextrow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Range("a" & nextrow) = shapeslide
    .Range("b" & nextrow) = shapename
    .Range("c" & nextrow) = shapetext
    .Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname
End With
Exit Sub

line1:
    MsgBox "No item selected"
End Sub

Sub writedata()
Dim c As Range
Dim shapeslide As Integer
Dim shapename As String
Dim shapetext As String
Dim friendlyname As String

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

With ActiveSheet
    For Each c In .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        shapeslide = .Range("a" & c.Row)
        shapename = .Range("b" & c.Row)
        shapetext = .Range("c" & c.Row).Text
        friendlyname = .Range("d" & c.Row)
        pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```